# How do Enchants work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I don't understand how I can take a +51 health Enchant level 15-25 and put it on my level 24 pauldrons and only get +20 health out of it. If someone can explain or reference a good explanation as to how this is determined I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a mechanic in The Elder Scrolls Online which makes Armour enchantments on Shoulder, Waist, Feet, or Hand armour pieces will be significantly weaker than the same enchantment would be on Head, Chest, or Legs armour. These are commonly known as "small enchants" versus "normal enchants".

Comment: But 70% of 51 is 36(ish). 20 health of 51 is nearer 40%...

Comment: Yah i would love to see something more concrete since the math isn't adding up, if you want the points atleast.

Comment: @Para I've been poking at the numbers since I posted this, and haven't seen anything like the OP described yet.

Comment: @BillyMailman ill try it again today and see if i get the same results. its possible my memory is failing me.

Comment: @Paralytic Yeah, my brief tests today seem to indicate it's somewhere in the 35% range; seems they must have weakened them even further since whenever the information on the small enchant mechanic came out. I've updated the answer for now, though I really wish I had an exact number/formula.